# Spring Data Rest/JPA cascade persist on patch

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-rest

I have two entities, `Book` and `BookEvent`. They are linked by a ManyToOne-Relationship, i.e. one Book can have many BookEvents.
I view Book as the aggregate root and have one Repository for the Book entity, but not for the BookEvent.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<BookEvent> events = new ArrayList<>();


    public List<BookEvent> getEvents() {
        return events;
    }

    public void setEvents(List<BookEvent> events) {
        for (BookEvent event: events) {
            event.setBook(this);
        }
        this.events = events;
    }

    public void addEvent(BookEvent event) {
        events.add(event);
        event.setBook(this);
    }

    public void removeEvent(BookEvent event) {
        events.remove(event);
        event.setBook(null);
    }
}
```

(Other getters/setters are omitted here).

```
@Entity
public class BookEvent {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="book_id")
    private Book book;
    private LocalDate date;


    @PreRemove
    private void removeEventFromBook(){
        book.removeEvent(this);
    }

    public Book getBook() {
        return book;
    }

    public void setBook(Book book) {
        this.book = book;
        if (!this.book.getEvents().contains(this)) {
            this.book.getEvents().add(this);
        }
    }
}
```

I now want to add a new event to the book after the book has been created. I use Spring Data Rest.

Creating the book with a `POST` and one event works fine:

```
{
    "title": "My example book",
    "events": [ 
        {
            "type": "BOUGHT",
            "date": "2017-05-09"
        }
        ]
}
```

Gives the answer:

```
{
    "title": "My example book",
    "events": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "date": "2017-05-09",
            "_links": {
                "book": {
                    "href": "http://localhost:8080/api/books/2"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

But if I then do a JSON Patch to append one new event, the event is included in the response to the PATCH request, but it is actually not saved in the database (a GET on the book afterwards does not return the event and when the database the column book_id is null).

```
[
    {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/events/-",
    "value": 
        {
            "date": "2017-05-09"
        }
}
]
```

When using the debugger, the `setEvents()` method is called on the initial POST request, but during the PATCH request, only the `getEvents()` method is called - no `setBook()` or `addEvent()` method. I think the problem is there.

Do I have a problem with my entity setup?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was my setup as a bidirectional OneToMany setup without a join table. The problem can be fixed in two ways:

- Create a join table. This is done by adding a `@JoinTable` annotation to the events attribute the Book class. This needs one additional table in the database, therefore I did not chose this way.
- Use a unidirectional OneToMany setup (see [Java Persistence/OneToMany](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany#Unidirectional_OneToMany,_No_Inverse_ManyToOne,_No_Join_Table_(JPA_2.x_ONLY))). This is only supported by JPA 2.x, but this was no problem in a Spring Boot 2.0 setup. The implementation looks really clean this way.

My code now looks as following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = ALL) //The cascade is important as otherwise a new event won't be saved.
    @JoinColumn(name="book_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private List<BookEvent> events = new ArrayList<>();

    //Standard getter and setter for getEvents() and setEvents()
}

@Entity
public class BookEvent {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="book_id")
    private Long bookId;

    //No getter/setter for bookId was necessary
}
```

No special getters/setters which update the reciprocal link were necessary. This will get a clean JSON response with SDR without a `_links` attribute on each event. Adding and deleting new entries work as well.

Comment: man I've done everything like yours ,but getting error when persisting child entity  - it doesnt get id of parent